# Не могу переместить папку rabbitmq-server.service в /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat, rhel

Не могу переместить папку в `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice`
Выдаёт ошибку прав доступа:

```
mv: cannot create directory ‘/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service’: Permission denied
```

Перемещаю папку от имени рута.
Пробовал дать папкам, участвующим в цепочке, доступ 755, тоже не помогло.

Comment: а куда Вы ее хотите переместить?

Comment: В папку system.slice

Comment: так оно уже там. Зачем Вы это делаете?

Comment: Мне нужно переместить папку rabbitmq-server.service в папку system.slice

Comment: это не есть причина. Это Ваше решение проблемы. Скорее всего Вы делаете это неправильно, так как каталог /sys - это виртуальная файловая система. В ней нельзя просто так взять и подвигать файлы (Вы же програмно не можете платку памяти  переставить или ядер процессору накинуть?). Скорее всего Ваша проблема решается другим способом (например, поправить какой-либо конфиг и перезапустить сервис)

Comment: Возможно Вы правы. Пытаюсь просто на виртуалке без интернета поставить RabbitMQ, перекачивая архивы с файлами с виртуалки , в которой есть интернет. И обнаружил, что в виртуалке, в которой всё запускается, в каталоге /sys есть папка rabbitmq-server.service

Comment: скорее всего этот файл копируется туда через systemd, когда сервис запущен